# How do I Authenticate and get Litecoin & Bitcoin Id in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cryptography, bitcoin, litecoin

My project has litecoin and bitcoin payment. I have to verify whether the payment is made by a specific user. How could I authenticate and get the user token address for validation with the recent transactions? in iOS.

All suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the tag of the user"?

Comment: their user id, for validating with the recent transactions.

Comment: Why not use the Coinbase SDK?

Comment: https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ios-sdk